# Metro Style Loading Js From Online

Tags: javascript, windows, microsoft-metro

I'm working with Visual studio 2012 ultimate on Windows 8.

I'm developing a html5/js metro-style-application.

I want to dynamicly load my js file from online. Like;

```
<script src="http://example.com/js/myJsFile.js"></script>
```

But metro application says;

> APPHOST9601: Can’t load http://example.com/Scripts/myJsFile.js. An
>   app can’t load remote web content in the local context.

How can I solve that problem ?
Thanks...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can only include external js files from pages running in the web context.

More about this you can find here:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh465373.aspx