# Windows Cordova - Jquery Mobile App - An app can’t load remote web content in the local context

Tags: javascript, cordova, windows-mobile, hybrid-mobile-app

I am trying to create a hybrid application on windows platform which has to load the Solr server data for a search drop down for auto completion. This has been successfully done on both android and iOS platforms. But on windows application, it throws an error as follows.

> APPHOST9601: Can’t load http://example.com/solr/my_core/select?fq=type%3Aname&fq=id%3A1&q=search_keyword%3Asearch&json.wrf=jQuery21404823221666457274_1469614324141&wt=json&rows=5&indent=true&_=1469614324142 An app can’t load remote web content in the local context.

Have anyone got any suggestion for the above given issue?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: see this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32832441/cordova-windows-phone-8-1-with-angularjs-an-app-cant-load-remote-web-content. It may help you

Comment: see this for a correct answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12627886/metro-style-loading-js-from-online